# Sliding Drawer issue in android

Tags: android-intent, android

I am using a listview and slidingdrawer in an activity. My intention is to open the slidingdrawer  and display the content upon list item click. slidingdrawer content will be changed depending on the item selected.

The UI layout is shown as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/presentation_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Presentation&apos;s Images.. Please Flip"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/content_imageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" 
            android:layout_below="@id/presentation_list"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

I click on the listview slider opens up, when i click on the slidingdrawer's imageview my listview is also getting clicked. The control gets to the listview item click method and image gets changed

Can anyone help me in rectifying the issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `android:clickable` attribute to your `content` layout and set it to be `true`:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true" >
```

Unfortunately, I cannot explain why it happens.